# How to go back to previous data randomly generated on same view controller

Tags: ios, xcode

I am new to coding and I am trying to code a random generator that displays random quotes. I am able to do that. But I want to be able to go back to previous quotes that I have generated and cannot find a way to do it. I have no xcode to show. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
var myQuotes = ["Adversity is The Universe's Way of Directing Us Down a Differnt Path", "Pain is Temporary, Glory is Forever", "As You Think, So Shall You Become", "If You Can Dream It, You Can Achieve It", "Dreaming, Afterall, is a Form of Planning"]

var randomGeneratedQuotes = Array <String>()
var currentlyShown : String?
var randomQuote: String {
    let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(myQuotes.count)))
    return myQuotes[randomNumber]

}

var previousRandom: String? {

    if currentlyShown == randomQuote {
        let previous = randomGeneratedQuotes.index(of: currentlyShown!)! - 1
        return randomGeneratedQuotes[previous]
    }

    return randomGeneratedQuotes.last
}




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    var randomQuote: String {
        let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(myQuotes.count)))
        return myQuotes[randomNumber]

    }
    quotesLabel.text = randomQuote

    func storePrevious() {
        if randomGeneratedQuotes.contains(randomQuote) {return}
        randomGeneratedQuotes.append(randomQuote)
}
}

//right hand button tapped

@IBAction func RHSButton(_ sender: Any) {

    var randomQuote: String {
        let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(myQuotes.count)))
        return myQuotes[randomNumber]


    }
    quotesLabel.text = randomQuote

    func storePrevious() {
        if randomGeneratedQuotes.contains(randomQuote) {return}
        randomGeneratedQuotes.append(randomQuote)
    }

}

//left hand button tapped

@IBAction func LHSButton(_ sender: Any) {


    func pressedBack() {
        currentlyShown = previousRandom


    }

    quotesLabel.text = previousRandom




}
```

}

Comment: Save your quotes

Comment: You can simply append those in an array and show the previous one?

Comment: Can you show us some code what you have done so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create var to hold the previous quote. and return it when user presses back. Or if you want all quotes to come after pressing back. You can keep a separate array for them like var generatedQuotes = Array(). And traverse the elements backward on the action. Just append the random element to the array or hold the lastQuote string in a var.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
     var myQuotes = ["A","b","c"] // your all quotes stored here.
     var randomGeneratedQuotes = Array<String>() // empty on start
     var currentlyShown : String?
     //use this not so random but will generate a random one
     var randomQuote: String {
       let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(myQuotes.count))) 
       return myQuotes[randomNumber]
     }
     var previousRandom: String? {
       if currentlyShown == nil {
          let previous = randomGeneratedQuotes.indexOf(currentlyShown) - 1
          return randomGeneratedQuotes[previous]
       }

       return randomGeneratedQuotes.last
     }
     func storePrevious() {
        if randomGeneratedQuotes.contains(randomQuote) { return } // already has
           randomGeneratedQuotes.append(randomQuote)
     }
     func pressedBack() {
       currentlyShown = previousRandom
       print(previous)

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. would you be able to provide an example of what the code might look like? I am very new to this

Comment: i've updated its not complete. but i think you get the procedure.

Comment: I really appreciate all your help but now I have the issue that when I press the button to go back, nothing appears. I think it is because nothing is being stored in the randomGeneratedQuotes array. Would you be able to help again? I have put my code into the initial question if that helps